# Asp.net core 2.2 TimeZone issues

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-core, timezone

When I use the following code, I get the wrong timezone on my project:

```
TimeZone localZone = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;
```

Because of this, I get a wrong time with the following code:

```
string dateTimeNowPlusForecaseHour = DateTime.Now.AddHours(hour).ToString("yyyyMMddhh");
```

When I create a new asp.net core console project, and I use the same code as the above, I get the right timezone and also the right time. What is happening here and how can I fix this issue?

Comment: `DateTime.Now` creates a loca time of the server where it runs. I don't get it where `localZone` can be used on your second code example. What do you get and what is your expected values exactly?

Comment: Hi, this first code line is used to get the timezone, I only used that line to see what time zone the datetime is based on. They apparantly differ on both my main project and the project i just created to test those kind of things.

Comment: We can only see the code you posted here, and it's unclear what you are asking.  You seem to be saying that when you use the code it doesn't work, but then when you use the same code then it does.  So what is the difference between the first time and the second time?  You haven't told us.  What specifically *is* the issue?  You say "I get the wrong timezone", but you haven't explained what you got nor what you expected.

Comment: Also, the `TimeZone` class is obsolete.  You should only use the `TimeZoneInfo` class.  This is [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezone).